# Modified Greenberg-Model

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I stuck on the following problem:
Consider the traffic flow problem for the modified Greenberg-Model
\begin{equation}
v(\rho) = \frac{v_{max}}{\ln(1+\rho_{max})} \ln \left( \frac{1+\rho_{max}}{1 + \rho} \right)
\end{equation}
with $0 \leq \rho \leq \rho_{max}$ and constant initial condition $\rho(x,0) = \overline{\rho}$.

1. Show that $u = a + b\rho$ with $a = \rho_{max}/(1 + \rho_{max})$ and $b = - 1/(1 + \rho_{max})$ satisfy a hyperbolic conservation law with convex flux function.
2. Suppose a traffic light is situated at $x = 0$. How does the corresponding boundary
   condition look like during the red phase $0 \leq t \leq T$?  Solve the initial-boundary
   value problem for  $u$.
3. At $t = T$ the traffic light turns green permanently. Calculate the time at which
   all vehicles are moving again. How long are there vehicles going with maximal
   speed?
   \end{enumerate}
   So far I got $(i)-(ii)$ and partially $(iii)$:

Rearring $u$ we get
\begin{equation}
\rho = (u-a)/b = \rho_{max} - (1 + \rho_{max})u
\end{equation}
and with $v_{ref} := \frac{v_{max}}{\ln(1 + \rho_{max})}$
I get
\begin{equation}
v(u) = v_{ref} \ln\left( \frac{1 + \rho_{max}}{1 + \rho}\right) = - v_{ref} \ln(1 - u).
\end{equation}
Therefore using the continuity equation
\begin{equation}
\rho_t + (\rho v)_x = 0 
\end{equation}
I get
\begin{equation}
-(1 + \rho_{max}) u_t - \partial_x \left( v_{ref} \ln(1-u)(\rho_{max} - (1 + \rho_{max}) u) \right) = 0
\end{equation}
or as conservation law
\begin{equation}
u_t + \partial_x \left( \frac{v_{ref}}{1 + \rho_{max}} \ln(1-u)(\rho_{max} - (1 + \rho_{max}) u) \right) = 0.
\end{equation}
Now the flux function is given by
\begin{equation}
J(u) = v(x,t) \rho(x,t) = -v_{ref} \ln(1-u)(\rho_{max} - (1+\rho_{max}) u)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
f(u) := -J(u)/(1+ \rho_{max}) = \frac{v_{ref}}{1 + \rho_{max}} \ln(1-u)(\rho_{max} - (1+\rho_{max}) u)
\end{equation}
is a convex function.
For $(ii)$ I got:
Position $x = 0$ of the traffic light and $T > 0$ being the red phase duration
\begin{equation}
\rho_0(x,t) = \begin{cases}
\overline{\rho} &, x < 0 \\
0 &, x > 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and therefore with $\overline{u} = \frac{\rho_{max} - \overline{\rho}}{1 + \rho_{max}}$
I get with the shock solution of the Riemann-Problem
\begin{equation}
u(x,t) = \begin{cases}
\overline{u} &, x < st \\
0 &, st < x < 0 \\
\frac{\rho_{max}}{1 + \rho_{max}} &, x > 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
s = \frac{f(\overline{u} - f(0)}{\overline{u} - 0} = v_{ref} \ln\left( \frac{1 + \overline{\rho}}{1 + \rho_{max}} \right) \frac{\overline{\rho}}{\overline{\rho} - \rho_{max}} < 0.
\end{equation}
For the green phase $(t \geq T)$ I get:
With the previous Riemann-Problem and the initial condition:
\begin{equation}
u(x,t) = \begin{cases}
\overline{u} &, x < sT \\
0 &, sT < x < 0 \\
\frac{\rho_{max}}{1 + \rho_{max}} &, x > 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Therefore there are 2 Riemann-Problems:

a) $\overline{u} > 0$: Shock $\psi(t) = st$, with the previous $s$.

b) Since $0 < \frac{\rho_{max}}{1 + \rho_{max}}$, a rearfaction wave starting from $(0, T)$.

Giving the solution for $t \geq T$ with $u_r = \frac{\rho_{max}}{1 + \rho_{max}}$:
\begin{equation}
u(x,t) = 
\begin{cases}
\overline{u} &, x < st \\
0 &, st < x < (t-T)f'(0) \\
(f')^{-1}\left( \frac{x}{t-T} \right) &, f'(0)(t-T) \leq x \leq f'(u_r)(t-T) \\
u_r &, x > f'(u_r)(t-T)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
which is correct as long as
\begin{equation}
st < (t-T)f'(0) \iff t < t_1 := \frac{f'(0)}{f'(0) - s}T.
\end{equation}
At the point where the shock interacts with the rearfaction wave we get
\begin{equation}
s(t) = \psi'(t) = \frac{f\left((f')^{-1} \left( \frac{\psi(t)}{t-T} \right) \right) - f \left( \frac{\rho_{max} - \overline{\rho}}{1 + \rho_{max}} \right)}{(f')^{-1} \left( \frac{\psi(t)}{t-T} \right) - \frac{\rho_{max} - \overline{\rho}}{1 + \rho_{max}}}.
\end{equation}
Now I want to solve this ODE with the inital condition $\psi(t_1) = s t_1$, but the complicated form of $(f')^{-1} \left( \frac{\psi(t)}{t-T} \right)$
makes it almost impossible.
I am not sure if I got the flux function right or I made a mistake.
I would be thankful if anyone can give me a hint what I did wrong.